# sql join using recursive cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> Edit: Added another case scenario in the notes and updated the sample attachment.

I am trying to write a sql to get an output attached with this question along with sample data.
There are two table, one with distinct ID's (pk) with their current flag. 
another with Active ID (fk to the pk from the first table) and Inactive ID (fk to the pk from the first table)
Final output should return two columns, first column consist of all distinct ID's from the first table and second column should contain Active ID from the 2nd table.
Below is the sql:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#main') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #main;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#merges') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #merges
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #final

SELECT DISTINCT id, 
       current
INTO   #main 
FROM   tb_ID t1 


--get list of all active_id and inactive_id 

SELECT DISTINCT active_id, 
            inactive_id, 
            Update_dt  
INTO   #merges 
FROM   tb_merges 
-- Combine where the id from the main table matched to the inactive_id (should return all the rows from #main)

   SELECT id, 
   active_id AS merged_to_id 
   INTO   #final 
   FROM   (SELECT t1.*, 
           t2.active_id, 
           Update_dt , 
           Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               partition BY id, active_id 
               ORDER BY Update_dt DESC) AS rn 
    FROM   #main t1 
           LEFT JOIN #merges t2 
                  ON t1.id = t2.inactive_id) t3 
  WHERE  rn = 1 

 SELECT *
 FROM #final
```

This sql partially works. It doesn't work, where the id was once active then gets inactive. 
Please note:

- the active ID should return the last most active ID
- the ID which doesn't have any active ID should either be null or the ID itself
- ID where the current = 0, in those cases active ID should be the ID current in tb_ID
- ID's may get interchanged. For example there are two ID's 6 and 7, when 6 is active 7 is inactive and vice versa. the only way to know the most current active state is by the update date

Attached sample might be easy to understand

[image: Sample data with expected output]

Looks like I might have to use recursive cte for achieiving the results. Can someone please help? 
thank you for your time!

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @Shawn - SQL Server

Comment: What does your initial data look like?

Comment: You are going to need to explain "**This sql partially works. It doesn't work, where the id was once active then gets inactive.**" because that makes no sense at all. You need to provide ddl and sample data along with the desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Shawn Have updated the attachment with the actual output and expected output. Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for sharing the link. it is really helpful.

Comment: What do `tb_ID` and `tb_merges` look like? What data do they have in them? You've done a good job of providing what you've tried and what you expect to get, but we need a starting point. I can't tell how you're building the temp tables you're working with. This _sounds_ like it's not an overly complex query to get at, especially with SQL server, but without base data, I can't be for sure.

Comment: @Shawn I apologize for not providing a clear picture. tb_id has list of all ID's ever generated. it may be possible that few of those ID got outdated due to various reason and were assigned new ID's. This is captured in the tb_merges table. it has a column with outdated ID's (Inactive ID) with a corresponding Active ID. It also has a date when the rows were updated. In the Final table, I want to get list of all the ID's with corresponding active ID's Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're correct that a recursive CTE looks like a good solution for this. I'm not *entirely* certain that I've understood exactly what you're asking for, particularly with regard to the `update_dt` column, just because the data is a little abstract as-is, but I've taken a stab at it, and it does seem to work with your sample data. The comments explain what's going on.

```
declare @tb_id table (id bigint, [current] bit);
declare @tb_merges table (active_id bigint, inactive_id bigint, update_dt datetime2);
insert @tb_id values
    -- Sample data from the question.
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (5, 0),
    -- A few additional data to illustrate a deeper search.
    (6, 1),
    (7, 1),
    (8, 1),
    (9, 1),
    (10, 1);

insert @tb_merges values
    -- Sample data from the question.
    (3, 1, '2017-01-11T13:09:00'),
    (1, 2, '2017-01-11T13:07:00'),
    (5, 4, '2013-12-31T14:37:00'),
    (4, 5, '2013-01-18T15:43:00'),
    -- A few additional data to illustrate a deeper search.
    (6, 7, getdate()),
    (7, 8, getdate()),
    (8, 9, getdate()),
    (9, 10, getdate());

if object_id('tempdb..#ValidMerge') is not null
    drop table #ValidMerge;

-- Get the subset of merge records whose active_id identifies a "current" id and
-- rank by date so we can consider only the latest merge record for each active_id.
with ValidMergeCTE as
(
    select
        M.active_id,
        M.inactive_id,
        [Priority] = row_number() over (partition by M.active_id order by M.update_dt desc)
    from 
        @tb_merges M
        inner join @tb_id I on M.active_id = I.id 
    where
        I.[current] = 1
)
select
    active_id,
    inactive_id
into
    #ValidMerge
from
    ValidMergeCTE
where
    [Priority] = 1;

 -- Here's the recursive CTE, which draws on the subset of merges identified above.
 with SearchCTE as
 (
    -- Base case: any record whose active_id is not used as an inactive_id is an endpoint.
    select
        M.active_id,
        M.inactive_id,
        Depth = 0
    from
        #ValidMerge M
    where
        not exists (select 1 from #ValidMerge M2 where M.active_id = M2.inactive_id)

    -- Recursive case: look for records whose active_id matches the inactive_id of a previously
    --                 identified record.
    union all
    select
        S.active_id,
        M.inactive_id,
        Depth = S.Depth + 1
    from
        #ValidMerge M
        inner join SearchCTE S on M.active_id = S.inactive_id
 )
 select
    I.id,
    S.active_id
 from
    @tb_id I
    left join SearchCTE S on I.id = S.inactive_id;
```

Results:

```
id      active_id
------------------
1       3
2       3
3       NULL
4       NULL
5       4
6       NULL
7       6
8       6
9       6
10      6
```

Comment: thank you for working on this. I tried using the sql with my tables and the query is running since 15 mins. Looks like a performance issue.

Comment: @Excited_to_learn - I mentioned in the comments of my original answer that you could experiment with using a temp table instead of a CTE for what I called "valid merges," but I should have been clearer. I have refactored the query thusly and the I/O statistics are looking a lot better. Please give the new version a try.

Comment: Hi Joe, while working with your query on my tables I figured there is one more logic missing, when the ID gets interchanged. For example, lets add two more id's in your table and name them ID 11 and ID 12. In the merge table, when ID 11 is active, ID 12 is inactive and vice versa. the query returns null for both the values whereas it should return 12 for ID 11 and null for ID 12. Please run your query again, I tried editing it and look at the results to understand it better.

Comment: @Excited_to_learn - My query will return null for 11 and 12 in that case because neither of the merge records you suggested satisfies the base case of the recursive CTE. And it's a good thing they don't, because if either of them did, the recursion would never terminate; it would just bounce back and forth between 11 and 12 until the `MAXRECURSION` level is reached.

Comment: @Excited_to_learn - Until this point you have done a pretty good job of describing the rules that should govern this query, but you have not really explained what any of this data _means_, and I think that's what's keeping me from understanding your latest condition.

Comment: regarding the 11 and 12 example, wouldn't having a date (update_dt) help decide which one to keep active? Regarding the nature of the data, I would not be able to know the exact reason of why this behavior happens. All I can say is these are patient id's and our company is a healthcare insurance company dealing with patients. We are redesigning our patient table to get all the distinct patient id's in one column and another column should have active iddeals with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171618/discussion-between-excited-to-learn-and-joe-farrell).